# Understanding chmod and setfacl

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, acl

I have a file that I think I should be able to execute. It shows these permissions with `ls -lah`:

```
-rw-rwxr--+ foo foo-group
```

And these with `getfacl myfile`:

```
# file: app/console
# owner: foo
# group: foo-group
user::rw-
user:root:rwx
user:foo:rwx
user:other-user:r-x
group::r--
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

I remember executing `` sudo setfacl -m u:`whoami`:rwx ``.

I think I got the setfacl command right, since getfacl shows `user:foo:rwx`. But I still can't execute it. Then what's the point of setfacl, if it can't override chmod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the `acl(5)` man page (yes, it is a bit confusing) as stating that the permission bits for the owner/group are always applicable to those, the ACLs are for *others*. E.g., you could give user `bar` permission to `rwx`, not `foo` (the owner's permissions are given by the standard permission bits). If my reading is correct, what you are doing is even illegal (there should be no repeat user/group entries in the ACL).